# Making a MySQL COUNT query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, left-join

after 4 days of tries and researchs over the web I can't make my wishes working.
Any help would be appreciated !
**Performed on MYSQL WORKBENCH**
I got a DB made of 3 tables :

| user | Posts | likes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| username | id | id |
| id | title | userId (foreign key from user.id) |
| email | content | postId (foreign key from posts.id) |
| password | date |  |
| image | imageUrl |  |
|  | userId (foreign key from user.id) |  |

I want a query that would take specifics datas from USER and POSTS plus a total count of likes for each post ordered by id of post and a total result of 0 if no likes exist with this id.
Here the list of what I want my query to do :

- Select specifics datas in USER and POSTS; *( working )*
- COUNT the total of LIKES for each POSTS and give me a total of 0 if any post has no likes;

My Actual Query :

```
SELECT P.id, P.userId, P.title, P.content, P.date, P.imageUrl, U.username, U.permission, U.image,
COUNT(CASE WHEN L.postId = P.id THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS totalLikes
FROM posts AS P
LEFT JOIN user AS U
ON U.id = P.userId
LEFT JOIN likes AS L
ON P.id = L.postId
ORDER BY P.id DESC;
```

This is returning only 1 post with a count of all the likes in database so not what i'm expecting :-(

Comment: It has no added value to add `Workbench`. This is about a SQL query, and it really does not matter which client you use. MySQLworkbench is just a client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregation inside `likes` only and then join the other tables to the resultset of the aggregation:

```
SELECT P.id, P.userId, P.title, P.content, P.date, P.imageUrl, 
       U.username, U.permission, U.image,
       COALECE(L.totalLikes, 0) AS totalLikes
FROM posts AS P
INNER JOIN user AS U ON U.id = P.userId  -- change to LEFT JOIN if the column userId in posts is nullable
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT postId, COUNT(*) AS totalLikes
  FROM likes 
  GROUP BY postId
) AS L ON L.postId = P.id
ORDER BY P.id DESC;
```